# AIR 15 on iOS 8 - Unwanted Push Notification anyway

Tags: air, ios8, push, alert

Since the upgrade of my devices for iOS 8, I keep having a Window Alert for Push Notification even on applications which haven't such notification : "MyApp Would Like to Send You Notifications"

After research, I've seen that it may be caused by an old AIR version.
Problem is that I'm already testing in the last AIR SDK version ( 15.0.0.249 ) and the push notification keep appear.

Otherwise, the real problem seems to be that in my others applications which allready have the push, it seems to make conflict when you refuse the push at the first opening. It cause freezing the application and force to kill it.

Does anyone have a clue ?
Thanks a lot,

Comment: iOS uses a series of "Entitlements" to give access to special features. in your *_app.xml manifest do you have a `aps-environment` under `<Entitlements>`?

Comment: Indeed I have one. For my Application Test, I haven't anything in this <Entitlements> but it's here where I put the values to calibrate the push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to the AIR 15 beta. This bug was fixed a week or two ago (though I can't find the release notes saying it was). The betas are stable in my testing and fix a lot of iOS 8-related issues.

http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html

Comment: In fact I've try the last version of the AIR SDK but it appears that this alert was related to all notifications comming from the application and ot just the push notification.
That's the reason why they keep coming.